Arrayformula with IF function in Google Sheets
I am trying to array a formula with if function but I am getting circular dependency error.
Sample Data
I want to copy dates from column A to B using formular =IF(D2="","", IF(A3="",B2,A3)) and it works if I drag down the formular. However, if I try to array the formula, I get circular dependency error. What alternative can I use in this scenario. Thank you.
Expected Result
